# iOS MagicalRecord Crash on launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm having an issue where some users are getting a crash on launch in my native iOS app using MagicalRecord (shorthand) v2.2.

This is not a classic database migration issue as firstly it doesn't occur for all users, and secondly the database schema has not been changed (I have git logs proving this and just in case I tried to reproduce after making some db changes but was not successful).

Deleting and recreating the database does seem to work however as the fallback code in the app clears and recreates the database if it has detected that it has crashed due to this issue previously. The crash logs indicate that this works as there is a 1 to 1 ratio of unique devices and number of crashes.

All that happens on launch related to the db is the following:

```
[MagicalRecord setErrorHandlerTarget:self action:@selector(handleCoreDataError:)];
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"xxx.sqlite"];
```

The stack trace on the main thread:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x37d3f626 objc_msgSend + 5
1  Foundation                     0x2dec102d -[NSError dealloc] + 60
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x37d44b6b objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 174
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x37d450d3 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 358
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2d4d24c1 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
5  Foundation                     0x2decb8e3 -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 122
6  CoreData                       0x2d312fbf -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 942
7  xxx                            0x00249223 __70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke3 (NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalSaves.m:64)
8  CoreData                       0x2d3769cd developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 88
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x3821ed3f _dispatch_client_callout + 22
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x382216c3 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 278
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2d569681 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
12 CoreFoundation                 0x2d567f4d __CFRunLoopRun + 1308
13 CoreFoundation                 0x2d4d2769 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
14 CoreFoundation                 0x2d4d254b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
15 GraphicsServices               0x3243f6d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
16 UIKit                          0x2fe31891 UIApplicationMain + 1136
17 xxx                            0x0002e3cc main (main.m:18)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this error seems like you're overreleasing the error object. Are you explicitly calling `[error release]` or `[error autorelease]` somewhere?

Comment: No I'm using ARC throughout the project, so there is no explicit release or autorelease calls being made on my part.